# Error starting application Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I run [this](https://github.com/dmitrykhramov/Online-Bank-Simulator) project and get an error

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project userFront: Command execution failed. Process
>   exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I was looking for a solution to the problem in Google, I tried such solutions.

```
mvn dependency::tree
mvn clean install -U
```

I noticed that the project launched the tests and tried to run it without them and got a similar error

[image]

> No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid
>   lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or
>   :[:]:.
>   Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
>   generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
>   process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
>   process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
>   test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package,
>   pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
>   install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean,
>   clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException

Comment: The error message which you specified is nothing but you are not specifying goal for maven build. you can specify any goal in your run configuration for maven build like clear, compile, install, package.

Comment: @MebinJoe Above there is a screenshot on which it is clear that I ran the maven with the goal of "no tests", what goal can I still choose to run in netbeans 8.2?

Comment: @MebinJoe MB I do not understand how to choose a goal? I right-click on the project and choose to launch the maven and set the goal there

Comment: For vm arguments use this: `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Comment: @Clover Попробовал запустить команду с папки проекта и ничего не вышло, ошибка осталась

Comment: @Apper Try the this `-Dmaven.test.skip=true `from the command line interface. I tried to reproduce the same issue but everything works fine for me in both IDE(Eclipse) and cli.